# C++ Function bind repeating arguments to curried function

Tags: c++, gcc, currying

I am trying to understand the concept of currying and calling a function which concats three strings but by passing only two strings and using the second argument twice.

However when I do this, the second argument is not getting sent to the function at all and it prints out an empty string. Is it some really obvious mistake?

```
string concatthreestrings(string a,string b,string c){
    cout<<"Value of A: "<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"Value of B: "<<b<<endl;
    cout<<"Value of C: "<<c<<endl;
    return a+b+c;
}


int main()
{
    typedef std::function< string( string,string) > fun_t ;
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    fun_t fn = std::bind( concatthreestrings, _1, _2, _2);
    cout<<endl<<fn( "First","Second")<<endl;

}
```

This is giving the below output. Doesnt using the _2 twice mean that second argument be passed for both second and third. If a use a string in its place its working fine.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting question, I would not have expected such a behavior!

Comment: Just to add some correction: This is not really currying. Binding arguments and currying are two very similar but still distinct operations, which should not be confused. Currying means to take a function which takes a function of N arguments and turn it into a function of one argument which returns a function of one argument which returns a function of one argument ... (repeated n Times). You can use `std::bind` to implement a `curry` function which does this for you (to some extend). Similarly you can use currying to implement argument binding in the way of `std::bind`.

Comment: @LiKao: Indeed, `bind` allow [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), not currying.

Comment: Thanks LiKao and Luc, I get the difference now. I was under the impression that in this particular example bind is being used to curry one function call to another

Comment: @LiKao, Luc Touraille: This behavior doesnt seem to  happen in VC++ compiler. Looks like its a GCC feature

Comment: I asked a follow-up to this question, which could shed some lights on your problem: [Is `std::function` allowed to move its arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10008503/20984)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copying strings is expensive. Since `std::bind` thinks that the values of the placeholders are only used once, it performs a `std::move` on the strings. This is done for each Parameter and as a consequence, either `b` or `c` is a moved, that means empty string.

You can change that behavior by explicitly saying what you mean, by passing the arguments by const-reference:

```
string concatthreestrings(string const& a,string const& b,string const& c)
```

Now, it should work.

Comment: Are you sure this behavior is well-defined? From what I read in the standard, the wrapper returned by `bind` forwards its arguments to the wrapped function. In this case, according to my understanding, we would have a wrapper along this way (after deducing the template parameters and collapsing): `string g(const char (&u1)[6], const char (&u2)[7]) { concatthreestrings(forward<const char (&)[6]>(u1), forward<const char (&)[7]>(u2), forward<const char (&)[7]>(u2)); }`. The three strings `a`, `b` and `c` would be constructed from the arrays, so I don't see where the move would occur.

Comment: @ipc: Is there some way where i can specify this behavior in the std::bind rather than changing the function definition itself

Comment: Accessing moved object is UB.

Answer (score 2):

I did a few tests using this smaller example that exhibits the same behavior you have:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

void print(string s1, string s2)
{
    std::cout << s1 << s2 << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    typedef std::function< void(string) > fn_t;

    fn_t func = std::bind(print, _1, _1);

    std::string foo("foo");
    func(foo);
}

// outputs: foo
```

Note that I defined a string object named "foo" instead of using string literals. The behavior is the same, so the problem is not related to this.

I think the problem comes from your typedef. The return of `bind` (which is unspecified) is casted to a function taking a `string` *by value*, while the wrapper returned by bind probably take its arguments by rvalue-reference and perfectly-forward them. Instead of using your own typedef, you should use the `auto` keyword, so that the type of `func` will be automatically deduced by the compiler. If we modify the main as follows, we obtain the expected behavior:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    auto func = std::bind(print, _1, _1);

    std::string foo("foo");
    func(foo);
}

// outputs: foofoo
```

Another solution is to replace your typedef so that `func` takes its parameter by reference-to-const:

```
typedef std::function< void(string const &) > fn_t;
```

I don't really understand why the other typedef does not work... Presumably the string is moved, as @ipc noted, but I don't know at what point of the execution this happens. I'm not even sure this is standard behavior, since both `function` and the wrapper returned by `bind` should use perfect forwarding. Perhaps GCC includes some optimizations that move the wrapper arguments when they are passed by value?

*Edit*

I did some tests, it turns out GCC's implementation of `std::function` performs a move on its arguments, while the wrapper return by `std::bind` does not. I still don't know if this is standard, I'm going to write a question about that.

Comment: ya I think its a compiler implementation issue since VC doesnt exhibit it.