# std::function copying parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct A {
  A() = default;
  A(const A&) {
    cout << "copied A" << endl;
  }
};

void foo(A a) {}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  std::function<void(A)> f = &foo;
  A a;
  f(a);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm seeing "copied A" twice on the console. Why is the object being copied twice, not once? How can I prevent this properly?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. What is `a`?

Comment: Sorry, deleted one line too much.

Comment: As I said, I fixed it. This isn't homework, I'm just trying to learn C++11.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008503/is-stdfunction-allowed-to-move-its-arguments) isn't a duplicate, but may help understand what's going on.

Comment: OK disregard my previous comment; hadn't seen the update. I'm seeing it three times as well (with GCC) and only once if I call `foo` directly. What Luc Danton suggested makes sense, but doesn't account for the third copy. Maybe the order and number of calls to the copy constructor is somehow undefined?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The specialization `std::function<R(Args...)>` has a call operator with the following declaration:

```
R operator()(Args...) const;
```

In your case, this means that the operator takes `A`. As such, calling `f(a)` results in a copy due to the pass-by-value semantics. However, the underlying `foo` target also accepts its argument by value. Thus there will be a second copy when the parameter to `f` is forwarded to `foo`.

This is by design, and in fact if `A` had a move constructor there would be only one copy followed by a move construction -- and calling `f(std::move(a))` would only result in two move constructions. If you feel that two copies are too much you need to reconsider whether both `foo` and `f` should take `A` instead of e.g. `A const&`, and/or whether `A` can have a sensible move constructor.

You can also do `std::function<void(A const&)> f = &foo;` without modifying `foo`. But you should reserve that for the case where modifying `foo` is beyond your control, and/or making `A` cheaply move constructible is not an option. There is nothing wrong with [passing by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592630/is-pass-by-value-a-reasonable-default-in-c11/7592741) in C++11, so I suggest that either both should take `A`, or both should take `A const&`.

Comment: Interesting. Do you also happen to know why are some of us seeing it getting copied *three* times rather than just twice? I'm using GCC 4.4.6 with `-std=c++0x` (it's an outdated network-wide install).

Comment: @smocking I suspect it is a defect in the implementation. My reasoning is based on the specification for the call operator, which boils down to "*Effects:* `INVOKE(f, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)..., R)` (20.8.2), where `f` is the target object (20.8.1) of `*this`." (there is also a *Returns:* clause but only for special-casing `void` returns). If I understand normative wording for the Standard library correctly then I don't think an implementation is allowed to copy/move more than passing to the call operator and the *INVOKE* operation require.

Comment: On the other hand, the algorithms are very notoriously known to be allowed to freely copy their functor arguments. This is only mentioned as a *non-normative* note, that is to say, the approach seems to be 'what isn't forbidden is allowed' (actual words from the relevant resolution in the defect list). So consider that those two copies/moves are a minimum. I leave it to anyone to consider whether minimizing those copies/moves is a matter of QoI or conformance.

Comment: Everything I do (when having move ctor also - VS11) I get at most only 1 copy. (even if everything is reference). I couldn't make it to have 2 moves

Comment: I made it to have 2 moves actually. Before I was using std::bind to bind foo to function f. As it seems it's less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It's being copied because you pass it by value. You could avoid all copies by passing it as a const reference instead.

Comment: That would account for just one copy. He's seeing it twice, presumably in relation to the behaviour of `std::function`.

Comment: I want it copied once, not twice.

Comment: @BoBTFish First copy occurs while passing to `std::function`'s `operator()`, then second copy happens when forwarding to `foo` which takes by value.

Comment: @LucDanton I thought of that, but I thought (and was guessing OP also thought) that `std::function` was supposed to avoid that?

Comment: How would I prevent that then?

Comment: @lucasclemente `std::function<void(const A&)> f = &foo;` works but I'm not 100% convinced it's correct yet.

Comment: I cannot make using const A& to not have less than 1 copy (have no copy/move at all). I wonder why is that considering you store a reference and call foo(const A&) also